# Trigger a GitHub workflow if two other workflows have been successful

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to understand how I could trigger a GitHub workflow based on two other workflows that has been successful. With some testing I have concluded that it always runs for some reason and even twice.

I have one workflow for building and creating a Docker Image for the backend, another one for the frontend then I have a workflow for deploying it to a testing environment.

This is my current configuration in the workflow for deploying to test environment:

```
name: Deploy to Test Environment

env:
  GITHUB_REGISTRY: "ghcr.io"
  GITHUB_OWNER: "mjovanc"
  GITHUB_DOCKER_IMAGE: "test"

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Backend Main Pipeline", "Frontend Main Pipeline"]
    branches: [main]
    types:
      - completed
```

In this workflow I also have set:

```
if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
```

Just to avoid the job being run if it is not successful.

Why is this one triggered twice and how can I make it wait for both to finish succesfully? It seems like if one workflow finishes earlier then it gets triggered, and then when the other one is finished, the workflow triggers again, thereof twice.

Comment: Your rules say it should be triggered when _either_ of them complete successfully, so when _both_ do it's triggered twice (as two workflow completed events are emitted).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the response. Then I understand. Is there any way of telling GitHub not to run unless both are finished successfully?

Comment: You could do it by converting the `Backend Main Pipeline` and `Frontend Main Pipeline` into reusable workflows. Those reusable workflows would be called in a workflow as jobs. Then, you could use the `needs` field waiting for the 2 reusable workflow jobs to conclude, before starting the job (a third one) you currently run in the `Deploy to Test Environment` workflow.

Comment: @GuiFalourd That was a perfect solution to my problem. If you write an answer on this I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve what you want by converting the `Backend Main Pipeline` and `Frontend Main Pipeline` into reusable workflows.

Those reusable workflows would be called in a workflow as jobs.

Then, you could use the `needs` field waiting for the 2 reusable workflow jobs to conclude, before starting the job (a third one) you currently run in the `Deploy to Test Environment` workflow.

Example:

```yaml
on:
  push:

jobs:
  job1:
    uses: <owner>/<repo>/.github/workflows/Backend-Main-Pipeline.yml@main

  job2:
    uses: <owner>/<repo>/.github/workflows/Frontend-Main-Pipeline.yml@main

  job3:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job1, job2]
    steps:
      # Deploy to Test Environment current job
```

Comment: I also noted that you could just write  `./.github/workflows/<workflow-file>.yml@main` if it's in the same repo. Just for others to know about if they stumble upon this. Great answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> If you specify multiple workflows for the `workflow_run` event, only one of the workflows needs to run.

This means that for your given workflow it will execute when "Backend Main Pipeline" **or** "Frontend Main Pipeline" have completed. Your workflow is running twice because the two workflows you are looking for both complete at different times thus causing your "Deploy to Test Environment" to run twice.

At the time of this writing, there isn't an out-of-box feature that allows you to wait for both workflows to complete. You will need to implement this logic in your workflow or change your approach to your deployments.

See [Events that trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows) for more details.